# How define permission on Firebase

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm having permission problems when I'm trying to do a query on Firebase Firestore.

This is the code that performs the query.

```
Future<void> fetchData() async {
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    CollectionReference diariosRef = db.collection("diarios");
    QuerySnapshot feveireiro = await diariosRef
        .where("data_publicacao",
            isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: DateTime(1, DateTime.november, 2023))
        .get();
    for (var doc in feveireiro.docs) {
      print(doc.data());
    }
  }
```

And i get this error:

> E/flutter ( 7158): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.

And this is how the permissions rules are set up in my Firebase:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Im also using Cloud Storage and Firebase Auth, but Cloud Storage has the same rules.

What is wrong?

Comment: How are you setting up your connection to the database? What does the initialization of your app look like? Your Cloud Firestore rules should allow any access.

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404) will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules should allow for any access but if you wanted to specifically add permissions to diarios you could try:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /diarios/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```